# Aurelia - Binding and updating a property in a custom element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I thought I would implement this quickly, but it has sent me down a rabbit hole.

I have a sidebar which is a custom element. It has 2 'modes', one for 'admin' pages and one for regular pages. There is a property in my sidebar.js that stores the mode. In the sidebar.html I use `show.bind="mode!=='admin'"` to show the admin part of the UI. When I change the value of the mode property in the constructor, it works as expected.

I can't seem to change the view with code.

The sidebar is part of my `app.html`:

```html
<template>
<require from="./elements/sidebar"></require>
<div id="wrapper">
    <sidebar mode="regular"></sidebar>
    <main>
       <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
</div>
```

Now I have **another view** that wants to change the mode of the sidebar. In that view's js I change the value of the mode property in the `activate` method (I make a reference to the sidebar via injection in the constructor):

```js
activate(params, routeConfig){
    this.sidebar.mode = "admin";
    ...
}
```

But nothing seems to get updated. This is my sidebar.js:

```js
import {bindable} from "aurelia-framework";
import config from 'config';

export class Sidebar {

    @bindable mode;

    constructor(){
        ...
        this.mode = "regular"; //default value is regular
        ...
    }
}
```

The value of the mode is changed, but my sidebar view (the html) is not updated.

I'm still new with Aurelia and web development in general.

What is the best *Aurelia way* of doing this?

Comment: Could you set up a plunker example?

Comment: I have never set up something like that before. But here are the adapted files that I discussed above: https://plnkr.co/edit/83MuwCO22Md0dYnVl3fQ?p=catalogue I don't know how to set it up for a fully working Aurelia app.

Comment: You can fork this Hello World App - http://plnkr.co/edit/5vMoxM?p=preview. Seeing a working example of the problem will help us solve the problem for you.

Comment: Hopefully this works:  http://plnkr.co/edit/PQYivoUWSqnUSpHs7qMU?p=preview

Comment: Try using a boolean value. Instead of testing `show.bind="mode!=='admin'"`, use `show.bind="isAdmin"` and `show.bind="!isAdmin"`.

Comment: Tried that before as well, but that doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: I have found a workaround involving the EventAggregator to listen to router events. Then, by inspecting the path I can determine if I need to change the mode. Feels like a hack though.

Answer (score 1):

Custom-elements are transient, which means that you will get a new instance whenever you inject them. To get your `Sidebar` instance by DI, you have to register it first. For example:

HTML:

```
<template>
  <require from="./sidebar"></require>

  <sidebar view-model.ref="sidebar"></sidebar>
  <br><br>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

JS:

```
import { Sidebar } from './sidebar';
import { Container, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Container)
export class App {
  constructor(container) {
    this.container = container;
  }

  bind() {
    this.container.registerInstance(Sidebar, this.sidebar);
  }

}
```

Then, you are able to inject it into your view:

```
import { Sidebar } from './sidebar';
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Sidebar)
export class Route1 {

  constructor(sidebar) {
    this.sidebar = sidebar;
    this.sidebar.admin = false;
  }

}
```

Running example: https://gist.run/?id=0bf1e32cdccc37ceebc57c2d74ba2ca0

Comment: Well, to be honest I've never done that, but that's is the only way I've found to pass the element instance by DI (which I believe is what the OP wants). Usually, I have an object that contains the application state, and I inject it into the elements... This approach can also be confusing if he has 2 or more Sidebar, because the DI will return the instance found in the nearest container...

Comment: Can you tell me what makes you icky? (here or in the channel) I like to discuss about programming strategies :) It is always a good opportunity to learn something

Comment: The tight coupling, first off, and second, I'm wondering how this would work if this were used in a page that wasn't the root page for the app (so the `registerInstance` code might get called multiple times. I'd probably go for an Event Aggregator based solution, though I'd prefer to rethink the design entirely to deal with this better.

Comment: Yeah, everything you said makes sense for me. Rethinking the design entirely would be definitely better. I'll update this answer with the problems you've mentioned so I don't confuse any future reader. If you also want to edit the answer, feel free to do it

Comment: Nah, I'm okay with your answer, it answers the question as asked. I just don't like the question :-)